# Algorithm that finds a permutation with a given property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need an algorithm that, given an ordered array A of N elements and a positive integer M, produces an array B such that one needs a minimum of M swaps to go from A to B; where a swap means switching two elements of an array.

I tried brute force, but the result is exponential and I can't seem to find an alternative.
I know little discrete math, but if you can explain your reasoning in simple terms, please feel free to do so.

(I'm not a native speaker, so feel free to edit)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s label the elements of A with the numbers 1 to N from left to right. Then array B is formed by placing elements 2 through M+1 at the beginning, followed by 1, followed by M+2 through N. Like so:

```
2  3  ...  (M+1)  1  (M+2)  (M+3)  ...  N
```

To prove this works, it helps to understand how cycles work in a permutation. A permutation breaks into disjoint cycles. The permutation (2,3,1) is a cycle of length 3, since 2 is in spot 1, 1 is in spot 3, and 3 is in spot 2. Elements which are unmoved by a permutation are in a cycle of their own. You can show that every transposition changes the number of cycles by exactly one. Since A has N cycles (every element is where is should be, so is in a cycle of its own), while B has N - M cycles (one big cycle containing 1 through M+1, and N-M-1 cycles of length 1), it takes M transpositions to get from A to B.